# Mongo sparse index cannot create

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm trying to create a sparse unique index, here's my data:

```
rs-ds119302:PRIMARY> db.trees.find({id_name:{$exists:true}, item_type:{$exists:true}}, {id_name: 1, item_type: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59417bf6748a2469ab093183"), "item_type" : 1, "id_name" : "AA" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59417bd7bc99346962fd289e"), "item_type" : 1, "id_name" : "BB" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59417bb4587803690be313bb"), "item_type" : 1, "id_name" : "CC" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599b6ff11e4d88264658e497"), "id_name" : "DD", "item_type" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("599f3fa8442b9d46e2340389"), "id_name" : "EE", "item_type" : 1 }
```

Index create command:

```
db.trees.createIndex( { id_name: 1, item_type: -1 }, { sparse: true, unique: true } )
```

Error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: ccp.trees.$id_name_1_item_type_-1 dup key: { : null, : 3 }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
}
```

Any thoughts on that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-compound-indexes):

> Sparse compound indexes that only contain ascending/descending index
>   keys will index a document as long as the document contains at least
>   one of the keys.

So your filter to find the indexed documents is not correct since the sparsed index will index all documents that have *at least one* of the two properties set. You would need to run the following query instead which should reveal the duplicate keys.

```
db.trees.find({$or: [ { "id_name": { $exists: true } }, { "item_type": { $exists: true } } ] })
```